# Can I use provided approach to access PHP variables in OOP?

Tags: php, class, oop, methods, parent

Here's some code to clarify the question.

Application.php:

```
class Application {
    var $class1;
    var $class2;

    function __construct() {
        include_once('Class1.php');
        include_once('Class2.php');

        $this->class1 = new Class1($this);
        echo $this->class1->testvar; // echoes 1

        $this->class2 = new Class2($this);
        echo $this->class1->testvar; // echoes 2
    }
}
```

Class1.php:

```
class Class1 {
    var $app;
    var $testvar = 1;

    function __construct($app) {
        $this->app = $app;
    }
}
```

Class2.php:

```
class Class2 {
    var $app;

    function __construct($app) {
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->app->class1->testvar = 2;
    }
}
```

What's wrong with this approach?

I noticed in some cases a recursion occurs and the consistency is not hmmm "consistent"...

Any help on the issue is appreciated.

Mainly I need to be able to access Class1 variables from Class2, extends didn't work well for these purposes.

Comment: what happens if someone does `new Class2` without ever having a Class1 instance around?

Comment: Well that would fail, but this order is bulletproof as it's in the application and there's no user input that could change the order.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$this->app->class1->testvar = 2;
```

is breaking the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter):

> The Law of Demeter (LoD) or principle of least knowledge is a design
>   guideline for developing software, particularly object-oriented
>   programs. In its general form, the LoD is a specific case of loose
>   coupling. The guideline was proposed at Northeastern University
>   towards the end of 1987, and can be succinctly summarized in one of
>   the following ways:
>
> - Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only
>     units "closely" related to the current unit.
> - Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers.
> - Only talk to your immediate friends.
>
> The fundamental notion is that a given object
>   should assume as little as possible about the structure or properties
>   of anything else (including its subcomponents), in accordance with the
>   principle of "information hiding".

Your `Class2` is making a lot of assumptions about what `Application` looks like, making the design of `Application` inflexible because `Class2` depends on it. You should only inject the immediately required dependencies into a class to preserve flexibility. `Class2` would look a lot better like this:

```
class Class2 {

    protected $class1;

    public function __construct(Class1 $class1) {
        $this->class1 = $class1;
        $this->class1->setTestVar(2);
    }

}
```

1. Make properties `protected` to encapsulate them.
2. If you require `Class1`, type hint for `Class1` and require `Class1`, not some intermediate object which you don't really need.
3. Use setter methods like `setTestVar` instead of setting public properties. Again: encapsulation. You also preserve the flexibility to change your internal implementation of `Class1` around, as long as the method `setTestVar` stays as it is. Think about using a **defined interface** between objects, not just mess around with other object's properties.

Answer (score 0):

just extend the class1 to access it's method and variable, and since class1 extends the class class2 you will also be able to access the method and variable it contains

You can try this,

application.php

```
include_once('class1.php');
include_once('class2.php');

class application extends class1{

    function hello(){
        // variable from class1
        echo $this->class1var."<BR>";
        // variable from class2
        echo $this->class2var."<BR>";
    }
}
```

class1.php

```
class class1 extends class2{
    public $class1var = 'hello';
}
```

class2.php

```
class class2 {
    public $class2var = 'world';
}
```

calling the method hello

```
$app = new application();
$app->hello();
```

result:

```
hello
world
```

Comment: While this may work in this limited example, it doesn't seem likely that this is an appropriate structure in practice. You only have one object instance, while the OP has three; that's a vastly different scenario and use case.